# Internal Server Error when using php cloud files with swift openstack

Tags: php, cloudfiles, openstack, openstack-swift

I am currently using php could files as API for swift on a SAIO install with tempauth .
Executing the php file:

```
 require('cloudfiles.php');
 $username="test:teste";
 $api_key="AUTH_tkfec9a726c0584d3d8f0150eb36446fd4";
 $auth = new CF_Authentication($username, $api_key);
 $auth->authenticate();
 if ( $auth->authenticated() )
     echo "CF Authentication successful \n";
 else
     echo "Authentication faile \n";
```

the execution didnt work because some authentication problem:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'AuthenticationException' with message 'Invalid username or access key.

The user name and the api_key are corrects (tested with swift command and I could make operation on containers on swift ? I am wondering how it works when authenticating ? any idea

Answer (score 1):

You don't give an auth host URL so the default will be https://auth.api.rackspace.com. This might be the problem.

Btw. you should wrap the function in an `try-catch` block.

```
echo "Authentication faile \n";
```

will never be called because `authenticate()` always returns true if it does not throw an exception.